# GridView and ListView in a single fragment

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-fragments

I am doing Android Application for shopping. I need to display products as grid as well as list like this:

https://lh6.ggpht.com/Ly21pAbBRIxAzHn2R119a37NexxtjG5RkQJV8vv0IoCywzksIhKNSCkzWikbUnH8bGY=h900-rw

I don't know how to do this using image button or tabs. Can I change layout of the fragment at runtime? Or I have use 2 different fragments? Please help me.

Comment: how does your `GridView` design look like? You could just have one `GridView` and change the number of columns.

Comment: even if i change the column, it does not look like list view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just look at this:

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ListView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tgrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GridView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:dividerHeight="10sp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.Adapter.FriendAdapter;
import com.example.bean.FriendBean;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView mlist;
private GridView mgrid;
private ArrayList<FriendBean> arr = new ArrayList<FriendBean>();
private FriendAdapter friendAdapter1, friendAdapter2;
private int slist = R.layout.list;
private int sgrid = R.layout.grid;
private TextView list, grid;
LinearLayout listid, gridid, tlist, tgrid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mgrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    list = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    grid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    listid = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listid);
    gridid = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridid);
    tlist = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlist);
    tgrid = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tgrid);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(
                "listgrid.json")));
        String temp;
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(temp);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close(); // stop reading
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String myjsonstring = sb.toString();

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
        JSONArray jsonarray = obj.getJSONArray("lg");
        Log.e("Length", "" + jsonarray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String num = jsonObj.getString("number");
            String url = jsonObj.getString("image_url");
            FriendBean bean = new FriendBean(url, num);
            arr.add(bean);
            Log.e("image_url", url);
            Log.e("number", num);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    tgrid.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    friendAdapter1 = new FriendAdapter(MainActivity.this, slist, arr);
    mlist.setAdapter(friendAdapter1);

/*****JUST LOOK AT THIS****/
    list.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gridid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            tgrid.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            friendAdapter1 = new FriendAdapter(MainActivity.this, slist, arr);
            mlist.setAdapter(friendAdapter1);
        }
    });

/*****JUST LOOK AT THIS****/
    grid.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gridid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tgrid.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            tlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            friendAdapter2 = new FriendAdapter(MainActivity.this, sgrid, arr);
            mgrid.setAdapter(friendAdapter2);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options:

1. Use RecyclerView
2. Have two different fragments
3. Have two different layouts
4. Use a Framelayout and switch visibility of sub views
5. Use a ViewFlipper or ViewSwitcher

Answer (score 0):

Why use two layouts when you can simply use RecyclerView and use an imagebutton to handle the clicks and when clicked you can use something like this

```
// The number of Columns
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and when the listbutton is clicked you can use something like this:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

I'm not sure whether it would work or not, its just an example,If you want to learn more about implementing girds and lists using RecyclerView and CardView, check out these tutorials I made:

[Custom Android lists with CardView and RecyclerView](http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/cardview/custom-android-list.html)

[Custom Android Grids with Images and Texts using RecyclerView](http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/recyclerview/custom-android-grids-using-recyclerview.html)